# functions with $f'(b)-f'(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find al differentiable functions $f:R\rightarrow R$, with: $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}, a<b,\exists c\in (a,b)$ so $f'(b)-f'(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$

Comment: What have you done by yourself ? It is not a good habit to write down the text of an exercice without any comment, saying in particular where your stuck.

Comment: I just had a look at your recent 10 questions : **all** of them are without any comment, any will to dialog with us. 2 of them have been closed for this reason. Moreover, you have checked only two of them: a question for which you have a satisfying answer **must** be checked. Don't consider this site as a self-serve and carry (for free) : you have people here ready to help you, you have seen it, but please, have a "sharing attitude".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite this as:
$$\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$$
Now, fix $b$, and consider $\{a_n\}$ where $a_n\to b$.
Looking at the limit, we have that:
$$\lim_{a_n\to b} \frac{f'(b)-f'(a_n)}{b-a_n} = \lim_{a_n\to b}f'(c)$$
Note that $\lim_{a_n\to b}f'(c) = f'(b)$, as $c\in (a_n,b)$.  Here we may be assuming continuity of $f'$ in case that matters (to pass the limit through the function). I'm not completely sure if it's required.

This means that:
$$f''(b) = f'(b)$$
for all $b\in\mathbb R$.

So, functions that satisfy this will satisfy the differential equation $y''-y' = 0$.
This has characteristic equation $r^2-r = 0\implies r(r-1) =0$, so general solution:
$$y = A_1 e^0 + A_2 e^{t} = A_1+A_2 e^{t}$$

Comment: see my comment above. My little experience on Math SE is that such people who are not fair with us do no deserve to be helped by full answers (in such a case, I give only hints) unless they change their attitude. It's up to you of course.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you do not assume continuity of $f'$?

Comment: I'm not certain assuming continuity is required.  In the limit we have that $c\in (a_n,b)$, so requiring $c$ be in that interval may imply $f'(c)\to f'(b)$.  But, as I'm not sure, I didn't state that.